# Getting properties from AEM multifieldpanel dialog stops working when a second entry is added

Tags: aem, sightly

I have created an AEM Dialog which prompts the user for a set of links and labels.
These links and labels are stored in a *jcr* node and are used to generate a menu.

To avoid having to create a custom xtype, I am using the **acs-commons** *multifieldpanel* solution, which enables me to nest children under the fieldConfig node.

This works great with only 1 Label/Link pair, but when I add a second one - the property cannot be fetched anymore, since instead of a String, it returns the String hashcode.

The property generated by the multifieldpanel in the jcr node is of type String and is filled correctly when inspecting in CRXDE. The problem occurs when I try to fetch the value from within a Sightly HTML file.

### Code

Dialog: 
[image: AEM Dialog]

Definitions.js:

```
"use strict";

use(function () {
  var CONST = {
    PROP_URLS: "definitions",
  };

  var json = granite.resource.properties[CONST.PROP_URLS];
  log.error(json);

  return {
    urls: json
  };
});
```

### Log output

#### 1 element in multifieldpanel

jcr node variable content

- `definitions: {"listText": "facebook", "listPath": "/content/en"}`

log output

- `{"linkText":"facebook","linkPath":"/content/en"}`

#### Multiple elements in multifieldpanel

jcr node variable content

- `definitions: {"listText": "facebook", "listPath": "/content/en"},{"listText": "google", "listPath": "/content/en"}`

log output

- `[Ljava.lang.String;@7b086b97`

### Conclusion

Once the multifieldpanel has multiple components and stores it, when accessing the property the node returns the String hashcode instead of the value of the property.

A colleague has pointed out that I should use the `MultiFieldPanelFunctions` class to access the properties, but we are using HTML+Sightly+js and are trying to avoid .jsp files at all cost. In JavaScript, this function is not available. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because, when there is a single item in the multifield, it returns a `String`, where as it returns a `String[]` when there is more than a single item configured.

Use the following syntax to read the property as a String array always.

```
var json = granite.resource.properties[CONST.PROP_URLS] || [];
```

Additionally, you can also use [TypeHints](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#typehint) to make sure your dialog saves the value as `String[]` always, be it single item or multiple items that is configured.

Comment: I have added a TypeHint to force the dialog to save as a String[] instead of String, but this does not solve the issue: the problem is when I try to access an Array in JavaScript with the `properties.get("var")` method, I get a `[Ljava.lang.String;@7b086b97` instead of the expected array of Strings. Any ideas?

Comment: The `[Ljava.lang.String;@7b086b97` is the array of Strings. When you try to print the value of a `String[]` as a `String` you see the above output. You need to loop through the array to access individual values.

Comment: Yes, just figured that out too! When looping over the properties in Js I can access the individual values. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the use() in JS is compiled into Java Byte code and if you are reading Java "primitives", make sure you convert them to JS types. It's part of the Rhino subtleties.

On another note, I tend to not use the granite.* because they are not documented no where, I use the Sightly global objects instead https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly/global-objects.html

To access properties, I use properties.get("key")

Hope this help.